# Receiving error (NoneType 'to_csv') while attempting to implement script into a GUI

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to build a small program that combines csv files. I've made a GUI where a user selects directories of the location of the csv files and where they want the final combined csv file to be outputted. I'm using this script to merge csv files at the moment.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


def add_dataset(old, new, **kwargs):
    if old is None:
        return new
    else:
        return pd.merge(old, new, **kwargs)


combined_csv = None

for csv in Path(r'C:\Users\Personal\Python\Combine').glob('*.csv'):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
    combined_csv = add_dataset(combined_csv, dataset, on='DateTime', how='outer')

combined_csv.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Personal\Python\Combine\combined.csv')
```

The script that I've built for the GUI is this: 
    from tkinter import * 
    from tkinter import filedialog 
    from pathlib import Path 
    import pandas as pd 
    import os
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")

```
# Setting up the 'Browse Directory' dialogs
def selectDirectory():
    global dirname
    global folder_path
    dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
    folder_path.set(dirname)
    print(dirname)

def selectOutputDirectory():
    global dirname_combine
    global folder_pathcombine
    dirname_combine = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
    folder_pathcombine.set(dirname_combine)
    print(dirname_combine)


# Printing the locations out as a label
folder_path = StringVar()
lbl1 = Label(master=root, textvariable = folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0,column=2)

folder_pathcombine = StringVar()
lbl2 = Label(master=root, textvariable = folder_pathcombine)
lbl2.grid(row=1,column=2)


def add_dataset(old, new, **kwargs):
    if old is None:
        return new
    else:
        return pd.merge(old, new, **kwargs)

def runscript():
    combined_csv = None

    path = r'%s' % folder_path
    combine = r'%s' % folder_pathcombine

    for csv in Path(r'%s' % path).glob('*.csv'):
        dataset = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col = 0, parse_dates=[0], delimiter = ',')
        combined_csv = add_dataset(combined_csv, dataset, on='DateTime', how='inner')
    combined_csv.to_csv(r'%s\combined.csv' % combine)


# Assigning commands to buttons to select folders
selectFolder = Button(root, text = "Select directory", command = selectDirectory)
selectFolder.grid(row=0,column=0)

selectcombine = Button(root, text = "Select output directory", command = selectOutputDirectory)
selectcombine.grid(row=1, column=0)

run = Button(root, text = "Run script", command = runscript)
run.grid(row=3, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

The problem I'm having is correctly implementing the script for the merging in the GUI script. The merge script works fine by itself but when I implemented it into the GUI script I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'". I think my function is setup in correctly in the GUI so I was reading the following documentation. https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html

I read that the "None" error occurs when there is no value being returned. So in this case I think it's not writing the variable "Combined" to a csv because nothing exists it in.

The complete error message is this:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Personal/Python//test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Personal/Python/Combine')

C:/Users/Personal/Python/Combine

C:/Users/Personal/Python/Combine

Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__

return self.func(*args)

File "C:/Users/Personal/Python/Combine/gui.py", line 54, in runscript

combined_csv.to_csv(r'%s\combined.csv' % combine)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Any help fixing the error would be greatly appreciated, as well as any advice on how to improve my code. I'm relatively new to Python and looking to improve. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with tkinter. `combined_csv` is `None`, which doesn't seem to be caused by tkinter.

Comment: My bad, I changed the title to something more fitting I hope. Thank you!

Comment: I guess that first two variables passed to `add_dataset` function are `None`, so maybe you should look into that. Is the directory selected properly before calling `runscript`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try creating an empty DataFrame and then write data to it and then hopefully I can save it as a .csv. The directory's are properly selected, so I think it's more the `add_dataset` function

Comment: Have you verified that `combine` is what you're assuming it is? The first step in debugging should always be to verify your assumptions.

Comment: The error was what @acw1668 suggested, but also I changed the `combine` to an empty DataFrame which would cause a `No columns to parse' Error. I had to change it `None`. It was a result of many errors in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `StringVar` in the following statements inside `runscript()`:

```
path = r'%s' % folder_path
combine = r'%s' % folder_pathcombine
```

Therefore no file will be found in the for loop below the above statements and `combine_csv` is not updated.

You should use `.get()` on the `StringVar` as below:

```
path = r'%s' % folder_path.get()
combine = r'%s' % folder_pathcombine.get()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity, does that mean that if I didn't use `StringVar()`, I wouldn't have to use `.get()`?

Comment: For your case, it is better to use `StringVar` because `lbl1` and `lbl2` can be updated automatically if the two `StringVar` are changed.  It really depends on the program design.